# vim: how do I set :match and :2match search results to different colors?

Tags: vim, search, gui, vi, syntax-highlighting

For example, I want something along the lines of:

```
:match search /<div/ guib=Green
:match search /<\/div>/ guibf=Blue
```

only that doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define highlight colors. From `:h :match`

```
:mat[ch] {group} /{pattern}/
        Define a pattern to highlight in the current window.  It will
        be highlighted with {group}.  Example: >
                :highlight MyGroup ctermbg=green guibg=green
                :match MyGroup /TODO/
```

So, something like this:

```
:hi OpenTag guibg=green ctermbg=green
:hi CloseTag guibg=blue ctermbg=blue
:match OpenTag /<div>/
:2match CloseTag /<\/div>/
```